# Subscribe to Twitter replies for a tweet that isn't mine

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to subscribe to Twitter replies to a tweet that isn't mine?

Maybe some external service?

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of subscription do you want? Like being being notified when a new reply is added to the conversation? Nope currently there's no way other then manual checking.

Answer (score 1):

Unless and until your @username is not in the thread, you cannot be notified for the replies.

Even if your @username is in the thread and someone replies to the thread by removing your @username, still you cannot receive the notification.

For the notifications to work someone has to mention your @username,or favorite the tweet you were mentioned in, or retweet your tweet, or follow you!